# php how to update all items within foreach

Tags: php, ajax

Hi I currently have a foreach that outputs me a number of items from an array, where the user can change the quantity of each item. For each item there is a button (update) where the user can click to update the quantity individually. Although I would like a single update button, where all items within the for each can be updated. How can i do this?

```
foreach ($allItems as $id => $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        <input class="quantity" type="number" value="'.$item['quantity'].'">
        <div class="btn-update" data-id="'.$id.'">Update </div>
    }
}
```

ajax

```
    $('.btn-update').on('click', function(){
      var $btn = $(this);
      var id = $btn.attr('data-id');
      var qty = $btn.parent().parent().find('.quantity').val();
        $.ajax ({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'mycart.php',
          data: {             
            id: id,
            qty:qty                 
          },
          success: function(data) {
          }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Sorry but that PHP code surely cannot compile?

Comment: it wont. i've just tried to make it shorter to what the actual code is.

Comment: @moleeee while that is a good thought, it still should run and show the problem. see 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to give a good problem example.

Comment: It does not really matter, you are obviously asking us to write new code for you to achieve what you say you want. We help each other fix code, we dont write new code for you

Answer (score 0):

Put the data-id attribute in the input field i.e.,

```
<input class="quantity" type="number" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>">
```

The in the ajax call you'll have to prepare the array with id and quantity:

```
$('#btn-update').on('click', function(){
  var data = [];
  $(".quantity").each(function() {
      data[$(this).attr('data-id')] = $(this).val();
  });
  $.ajax ({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'mycart.php',
      data: data,
      success: function(res) {
          // logic after ajax call
      }
    });

});
```

Transfer the update button outside the outer foreach and put the id of that as "btn-update".

Comment: thnaks for the answer but i want a button outside the for each which will update all items within the for each

Comment: Use a custom button outside outer for-loop and give the id as "btn-update". Then you can update the quantities in the php file as you are getting an array of items with index as id and value as qty.

Comment: im sorry but i dont understand. i have a button outside it, but how do i send all the data-ids and all data-quantities to ajax. i dont get it. Could you please provide the code for it

Comment: i have already provided the code for it above in the jquery where data is the array.

Comment: im sorry it doesnt seem to work. you can take a look at the repo if you like

Comment: if you do open the example.php and see if you can add a button, to update all in cart

Comment: I have modified the file. Here is the link https://gist.github.com/testz2104/e33fbc5301e2205f92880ecdd4e1c425. Please copy it as I will delete it after 1 hour. Please try this and let me know whether its working.

Comment: hey thanks i get the alert but how does this actually update it?

Comment: I have given you the array, according to the code in the question, you have used the AJAX call to mycart.php. So send this array instead and modify your php code to update the quantities as now you have the array with index as item id and value as item quantity. This is exactly what I had mentioned in my answer.

Comment: ahhhhh i see but the problem with this is that you can have different colors with the same product id.

Comment: that is not what you had asked in the question. you wanted to have a general update button so I have given you the code for general update button. there is no mention of colors in the question.